# How can I explain Scrum Master role to my grandma?

Tags: scrum, agile, scrum-master

Most of the Scrum Masters came to situation, that they want to describe their role to people without knowledge about agile, about development processes even about software developing etc..

How can you explain - to your mother, grandma, friends in pub - what are you doing at work?

Comment: I think you're really asking how to explain Scrum...

Comment: I usually go with something like a team coach

Comment: The Scrum Master focuses on helping the Scrum Team do the work necessary to deliver product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Scrum Master you act as a coach.

You guide the team continually improve so they can perform at their best and help remove obstacles so that they can focus on their work.  You work with management in order to promote a more productive working environment.  ...

http://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#team-sm

Answer (score 1):

The Scrum Master is often considered a coach for the team, helping the team do the best work it possibly can. Scrum Master as similar to a personal trainer who helps you stick with an exercise regimen and perform all exercises with the correct form. A good trainer will provide motivation while at the same time making sure you don’t cheat by skipping a hard exercise.

Answer (score 0):

A Scrum Master is a role in a team which uses Scrum, which is one of the Agile methodologies of software engineering.

Scrum Master is a servant-leader of the team. 
He is a person responsible for:

- maintaining proper understanding of Scrum in the team
- facilitating Scrum events (meetings), which are ment to make work of the team transparent to others (like stakeholders, managers, etc) and to adapt (be agile) what the team is doing to current requirements
- solving the problems, which team faces (not only technical ones, but organisational as well)

Comment: I don't know about your grandma, but my grandma would not understand a *word* of what you are saying.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like an ELI5 question.

I'll be quoting this:

> A Scrum master is a role in a team which uses a set of methodologies
>   called Agile. A scrum meeting is a moment where the team team members
>   talk about what they are doing, how they are going and if there are
>   problems (blocks on the road) to achive the project goal. The scrum
>   master coordinates this meeting; he reminds people of which are the
>   current goals. Sometimes he is also responsible for the organization
>   of other artifacts of the agile methodology like Kanban. If you
>   were a kid in a new school the scrum master would be the kid which
>   shows you around, help you to find your locker, introduce you to new
>   people, help you to organize the books, etc. Notice that the scrum master is not a boss but a
>   mediator of the interests of the project.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2spe3n/eli5_scrum_masters/cnro7hv

I suggest for things like these, just Google "• *what you want explained in simpler terms* • ELI5".

Comment: Thanks for showing me ELI5 forum - I didn't know it before.
The copied answer is quite misleading, there are objections in point of fact. I think A Scrum master is a role in a team which uses Scrum. :) "Set of methodologies called Agile"? What is that? Do you understand what is Agile? And do you know what is Scrum?